# Android Matrix postRotate and postTranslate applied to a Bitmap

Tags: android, matrix, android-bitmap

Here is a code snippet which I wrote trying to understand [Matrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) (`postRotate` and `postTranslate` to be more exact).

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mImageView2;

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn:

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                matrix.postTranslate(200, 0);

                Bitmap bitmap =
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, null);

                Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bitmap,
                        0,
                        0,
                        bitmap.getWidth(),
                        bitmap.getHeight(),
                        matrix,
                        true
                );

                mImageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);
        mImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    }
}
```

**XML layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="sample2.com.sample_app.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the bitmap is rotated but not moved anywhere:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: translate is ignored in `Bitmap#createBitmap()`

Comment: @pskink, can you please give a more detailed explanation? Is it documented that `translate` is ignored in createBitmap?

Comment: no it is not, i mean it is ignored but of course not documented, life is not always easy

Comment: if you want to learn the matrix then write a custom `View` and override `onDraw` method like this: `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null)`

Comment: oh, forgot `scaleType=matrix`, you can use `ImageView` too, just use `android:src=...` and call from java code `setImageMatrix(matrix)` - do not call `setImageBitmap`

Comment: @pskink, translation and rotation work with a custom view

Comment: good, but you can use `ImageView` too: see my prev comment

Comment: @pskink, write an answer if you want. if nobody else replies this week, I'll accept yours